# How can I create one uv map for multiple objects?

Tags: uv, objects, edit-mode

How can I unwrap multiple objects so that all meshes get unwrapped on the same `uv` map?
I have this tent, and I want to "paint" on it.
[image: Screenshot 1]

I tried selecting all the objects in this scene and unwrap but some edges became red (in `edit mode`). I don't know why.
[image: Screenshot 2]

Also, after marking the seams, the `smart uv` mapping option is missing.
So how can I unwrap all these objects in one `uv` map?

Comment: to have all of the objects on the same UV map they would need to be joined (Ctrl+J) into a single object and unwrapped.

Comment: and why some corners are red? Like in the photo

Comment: No, you can link UV maps for identical objects

Answer (score 8):

In Blender 2.8 and beyond you can enter edit mode with multiple objects selected.

### Before Blender 2.8

### Simple answer: *"you can't"*

Because a UV map pertains to each individual object, and only shows in the UV/Image editor while in edit mode, you cannot combine UV maps, or see multiple maps at the same time. (You can only enter edit mode for one object at a time.)

### Longer answer: *"you don't have to"*

Most likely, your best solution is to select all the meshes (**not** cameras or lights) and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to join them into one mesh. Now you can unwrap them all as if they were one mesh, because they are.

*Tip: You may want to reset the origin after doing this. (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) -> "Origin to Geometry"*

There are also some add-ons that help with generating UV maps that fit with others in the scene, for creating one large texture for all objects, instead of many different textures for each object. Try pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> and typing "UV: Texture Atlas" in the add-on search box. This might help you.

Comment: I did that CTRL-J but i dont know if they became one mesh, my scene tree looks the same. How do i know that?

Comment: After marking (again) the seams, i did "Unwrap" but my uv map is blank. Why??? I tried doing a "Smart Uv Project" but its the same result... a blank uv map...

Comment: I can't really say for sure. There are so many possibilities, and I am not seeing that is actually happening. Screenshots or a blend file upload might help. About joining, most likely the join failed because you had sometime besides meshes selected (the camera or lamps, most likely). I'm not sure why your UV map isn't showing up, but I can't really give a guess until I have more info

Comment: @UncleSnail I wonder if i have a model made of 20 object, made only one or few primitive meshes each. is combining maps of each of them unnecessary?

PS:im a newbie modeller. And consider my model is better have to be in seperate objects, if UV combining uv's doesnt effect anything at all.

Comment: for anyone in 2019 or later viewing this, now you can  edit multiple objects at a time if you are using blender 2.80 or later.

Comment: If you ctrl J then you have to incorporate the different objects into the same mesh. If you don't the triangles and UVs will overlap.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple answer: Yes you can!**

There is a free addon called 'Multi Object UV Editing' which you can download from github at https://github.com/ndee85/Multi-Object-UV-Editing
I am using this addon myself, it works like this:
Select multiple objects and press the 'Multi Object UV Editing' button from the tool panel in the 3D view.

[image]

It will then temporarily combine your objects into one and open the UV editor as one. Once you are done editing and switch out of the edit mode (tab key) it will transfer the UV changes to the previously selected objects. It's pretty seamless.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to do this without add-ons.

- Simply select all the objects you want, the last one should be the one that you want to edit. Then go into Edit mode.
- Then, in the UV Panel, go to the menu "View" and check "Draw other Objects"

There is a tutorial on Youtube as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbJbZU3B-Vo

Answer (score 0):

I choosed all objects in "Blender 2.8" switched to edit mode, and chosed all of faces by pressing "A" key.
Then i and unwrapped just like unwrapping 1 object.

I guess 2.8 suports uwrapping and displaying all chosen objects at the same time.

I hope this action was not a glitch :)